# Is there a public LinkedIn API to get my current follower (not connections) count?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am hoping to create a LaMetric app (for my own personal use) to show my current follower count for my LinkedIn profile.

This needs to be obtained using the public API as to avoid the risk of account ban, and should provide the follower count for my personal profile and not and organisation or page.

Is there a way to obtain this information through the public API? I am also open to alternatives that do not break the EULA if there are any.

I have tried reviewing the documentation on the Microsoft Docs, and I have successfully been able to obtain the information from the Voyager API but this does not meet the requirements as I believe it breaks the EULA.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/organizations/follower-statistics). LinkedIn's API is mainly oriented around brand advertising.

Comment: @Ouroborus - Unfortunately it looks like this API is for company/organisation pages and doesn't apply to regular profiles for people. Thanks though!